# Google BigQuery, unable to load data into shared datasets

Tags: google-bigquery

I created a project on Google BigQuery and enabled billing.

Went on to create few datasets that were shared with my team members (Can EDIT premissions).

However, my team mates are unable to load data into the respective datasets shared with them. Whenever they try it says billing not enabled for this project.

I am able to load data into the datasets but not my team.

It's been more than 24 hours

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Note that in order to load data, they need to run a load job, and that load job needs to be run in a project. Perhaps billing is not enabled on the project they are using?

You can give your team members read access to the project (or greater) to allow them to run jobs in your own billing-enabled project.

Comment: "Read (or) View" access doesn't help. But giving the members " Write (or) Edit" access works.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a BigQuery project at the **project** level and at the **dataset** level.

See https://developers.google.com/bigquery/access-control.

I assume you are sharing at the dataset level. Can you try sharing the project instead with your team members? (here: https://cloud.google.com/console/project)

Please report back!

Comment: I had to give "Edit" permissions to all the team members at project level and it works.